# What are the chances of acceptance after being asked to submit a revised version?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journal-workflow

I received the following response from a journal editor: "The reviewer(s) would like to see some revisions made to your manuscript before publication. Therefore, I invite you to respond to the reviewer(s)' comments and revise your manuscript. If you decide to revise the work, please submit a list of changes or a rebuttal against each point which is being raised when you submit the revised manuscript."

I have since submitted a revised manuscript along with detailed responses to the reviewers. I am waiting. How am I to view the chances of the manuscript being accepted?

Comment: Being asked to hand in a revised manuscript points towards acceptance. Most rejections do not happen after several rounds of review, but after the very first one when the editor will inform you that your paper is rejected.

Comment: Nobody wants to waste time. If they wanted to reject it, they would do it right away. Asking for revisions means that they have a reasonable expectation that those revisions can help make the paper publishable.

Comment: As phrased, there is an implication that the manuscript is accepted (albeit with minor revisions).